# While creating Cloud composer 2 using terraform, it is showing error i.e. Could not configure workload identity: Identity Pool does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-composer

Error: Error waiting to create Environment: Error waiting for Creating Environment: Error code 3, message: CREATE operation failed. Could not configure workload identity: Identity Pool does not exist (PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog). Please check that you specified a valid resource name as returned in the `name` attribute in the configuration API.
│
│   with module.resources.google_composer_environment.composer_env,
│   on ../terraform-common/resources/tf-resources.tf line 714, in resource "google_composer_environment" "composer_env":
│  714: resource "google_composer_environment" "composer_env" {
│

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same error, but running the creation from the Web console.

The problem for me was that the Service Account of the environment needs to have the "Cloud Composer v2 API Service Agent Extension" role, and it is related to that Identity Pool error.

This is mentioned in the documentation, but it is not clear:

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/create-environments

Comment: Hi, I also run into this issue. Did you mean Composer Service Account or Composer Service Agent account? The documentation says that Composer Agent Account needs to have this binding.

Comment: I had to add it to the service account that is chosen during the environment creation, not sure which one is it. According to the tooltip: "This service account runs the pods of your environment and performs environment operations such as upgrading your environment to a new version."

Comment: I have added this role to the Service Agent Service account (do not mislead with Composer Service Account, please). Service Agent account has a form like `service-{GCP_PROJECT_NUMBER}@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.
Also, I added roles/composer.worker role to the Service Aggent account. It seems all works fine now.
|

Comment: It is resolved now....that time the composer team was working on that